# Dynamically adding to ArrayList and displaying in gridview

Tags: c#, arraylist, session-variables

I am trying to add elements from a textbox on a button click to a grid view. Every time the user hits the button, I want it to add on another element to the end.

Currently, the [0] element gets overridden each time the button is clicked and displays only the most recently added string value. I am also trying to add the arraylist to a session variable.

How can this be done better?

```
public string InputArray;
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

private void BindData()
{
    SuffixGridView.DataSource = myArrayList;
    SuffixGridView.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InputArray = suffixTextBox.Text;
    Session["postFix"] = (ArrayList)myArrayList;
}

protected void SuffixButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myArrayList.Add(InputArray);
    BindData();
    suffixTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Must you really use an `ArrayList`?  Unless you are foced to use .NET 1.1, a `List<T>` is a much better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page_Load` overrides `Session["postFix"]` with the current myArrayList every time -- even on `SuffixButton_Click` (or rather on `Page.IsPostBack`).  Instead, load myArrayList from Session on postback.